# Can all DirectX11 games be deployed to Xbox One?

Tags: c++, xbox

If I program a game with DirectX 11 and C++ and make my own implementation can I deploy it on an Xbox one to test it? Otherwise, what do I need to do so?

Comment: That depends on what technologies *besides* DX11 you are using.

Comment: so that means i cannot just do it with that, i think i must use some dev xbox kit, but i was thinking all consoles are full compatible with c++

Comment: If you use some API which isn't supported by the XBox One, then it will of couse not work. And there are just too many to list them all.

Comment: Note that you're limited to feature level 10. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2017/12/15/directx-and-uwp-on-xbox-one/

Comment: See latest status on UWP on Xbox in [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-uwp-on-xbox-series-x-s/).

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is: **yes, you can**.

As stated on the [ID@Xbox webpage](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers/id) for independent game developers:

> **Can I use my retail Xbox One as a developer kit?**
>
> Yes, you can. Once you download the preview version of the Xbox Dev Mode Activation app, you can unlock dev mode on your Xbox One and experiment with creating games for a "10 foot" living room experience. You don't need to be part of ID@Xbox to get started, but we're here to help if you want to ship a UWP game on Windows 10, or ship a game on Xbox One.

That means you can use a commercial console and turn it into a testing environment for your games. That's all if you are working on your own, at least: if you are developing a game [using an engine like Unity](https://answers.unity.com/questions/768987/how-to-test-my-game-on-xbox-one.html) you are required to register.

By the way registration is free, as stated on the site:

> **What will it cost me?**
>
> There are no fees to apply to ID@Xbox, to submit a game to
>   certification, publish, or update your games. There is a very modest
>   one-time cost associated with development for the Universal Windows Platform.

You are paying only if you want your game to include UWP features, such as gamertags, achievements, dedicated multiplayer services, and so on.

To use developer mode, you need to download the Dev Mode app on your console from the store that lets you switch between *retail mode* and *developer mode*. There are several guides and how-to's, on the [Windows Dev Center page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/devkit-activation) there's a deep explanation of *developer mode* as well as other steps; also take a look to these articles on [Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/2016/3/30/11318568/xbox-one-dev-kit) and [Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-activate-dev-mode-your-xbox-one-console), Polygon's is clear about differences between free and paid preview of dev mode as well as their limitations. Check the [FAQs](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/apps/developer-mode-activation-app-faq) if in doubt.

Finally, if you want to set up your development environment and try to make a simple Hello World app, you can follow [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/development-environment-setup) found in the Microsoft Developers documentation.

Comment: im thinking on that possibility but i understood that i had to publish a game under ID@XBOX, so currently i dont have any game they can review and im not a game studio, i want to start messing with they tools, but i dont know how.